# socket() - error: variable client might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have written a very simple client program

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   private Socket cSocket;

   public GreetingClient() throws IOException
   {
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 5063;
        cSocket = new Socket(serverName,port);
   }


   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      GreetingClient client;
      try
      {
          client = new GreetingClient();
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
                InputStream inFromServer = client.cSocket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

                System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   }
}
```

When I compile this program I get the error that

```
GreetingClient.java:33: error: variable client might not have been initialized
            InputStream inFromServer = client.cSocket.getInputStream();
                                       ^
1 error
```

What does this error mean? if the new Socket() call fails (for e.g if too many sockets are open) then does this mean that I can't use it down in the code? How do I handle situations 
like this.?

Comment: It means what it says. Consider the case when the exception happens. You have the catch block in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
{
    client = new GreetingClient();  // Sets client OR throws an exception
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();            // If exception print it
                                    // and continue happily with `client` unset 
}
```

Later you're using;

```
// Use `client`, whether set or not.
InputStream inFromServer = client.cSocket.getInputStream();
```

To fix it, either set client to `null` where you declare it (which may cause a nullref exception later on use), or don't continue "blindly" after printing the exception (for example, print and return).